# Testing a Java application with an in-memory Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, integration-testing, in-memory-database

I am trying to figure out how to convert some tests that currently execute against a standalone Oracle DB to rather execute against an in memory Oracle DB.

We have a bit of an unusual persistence mechanism, in that we don't use JPA/JDBC, but instead all insert/update/delete operations are performed by invoking an Oracle stored procedure.

What I would like is to have the embedded database loaded with all the stored procedures that we use and the data setup with DBUnit.

I've done this before with JPA/H2 but I am at a bit of a loss on what to do this time.

Can anyone offer me some guidance?

Comment: And what is the driver for this conversion?

Comment: Are you referring to Oracle TimesTen?

Comment: No this a Java EE application that used Oracle Stored procedures for all CRUD operations.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the questions is with resect to the In-Memory DB?

Comment: It's because i would like to use an embedded DB for performance reasons...

Comment: So you are *not* talking about Oracle's Database In-Memory product (DBIM)?

Comment: Not specifically, but I am trying to find out what solutions are available for embedding an oracle DB in the same JVM as the application and application server that I would like to integration test.